# получение параметров объекта из массива объектов

Tags: java

Класс, в котором хранится массив:

```
public class SchoolBoard {


public ArrayList<School> scli = new ArrayList<>();



public SchoolBoard()
{

    scli.add(new School(0,20,0,"Ugly"));
    scli.add(new School(30,20,50,"Normal"));
    scli.add(new School(50,20,100,"Best"));

}
```

Как из другого класса получить параметры этих объектов? например (0, 30, 50)
С остальными я по аналогии разберусь)

```
public class VeryRichFamilys {

SchoolBoard sclb = new SchoolBoard();

public void chooseSchool()
{

        for (int i = 0; i<sclb.scli.size(); i++) {
           ???????????????????????

        }
 }
```

Класс School

```
public class School {
    private int education = 0;
    private int space = 20;
    private int cost = 0;
    private String name = " ";
    //-----CONSTRUCTOR------
    public School(int education, int space, int cost, String name) {
        this.cost = cost;
        this.space = space;
        this.education = education;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: А где класс `School`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужны либо публичные поля класса, либо геттеры. Последнее считается правильным.

```
public class School { 
  private int education = 0; 
  private int space = 20; 
  private int cost = 0; 
  private String name = " "; 
  //-----CONSTRUCTOR------ 
  public School(int education, int space, int cost, String name) { 
  this.cost = cost; this.space = space; this.education = education; this.name = name; 
  }
  public int getEducation() { return education; } 
  /* и так далее */
```

по вопросу:

```
public class VeryRichFamilys {

SchoolBoard sclb = new SchoolBoard();

public void chooseSchool() {
   for (int i = 0; i<sclb.scli.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(sclb.scli.get(i).getEducation());
   }

   for(School s: sclb.scli) {
     System.out.println(s.getEducation());
   }

   sclb.scli.forEach( s -> s.getEducation() );
 }
```

Comment: Отлично, помогло, спасибо :)

Comment: добавил еще несколько способов обойти всю коллекцию, каждый следующий лучше и современнее предыдущего.

Comment: Благодарю)) 
последний способ вижу в первый раз :)